# Initiating DELETE request batman.js and rails 3 from index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, indexing, view, batman.js

I am creating a rails 3 app using batman.js for the front end. I am able to submit a successful delete request when I'm in the `show.html` view of an individual record. But when I am in the `index.html` view, the same pattern is not triggering the delete method. I am guessing there's a little magic occurring when Batman.js triggers a delete request which I do not understand. Probably something to do with the scope of the `venue` variable in the `index.html` view. I'll show my code for the controller and the two views in question. If you need something else, please ask.

**/app/assets/javascripts/controllers/venues_controller.js.coffee**

```
class Plansandpictures.VenuesController extends Batman.Controller
  routingKey: 'venues'

  index: (params) ->
    @set 'newVenue', new Plansandpictures.Venue
    Plansandpictures.Venue.load (err, venues) =>
      @set 'venues', Plansandpictures.Venue.get('loaded')

  show: (params) ->
    Plansandpictures.Venue.find parseInt(params.id, 10), (err,result) =>
      throw err if err
      @set 'venue', result

    @render source: 'venues/show'


  create: (params) ->
    @newVenue.save (err, venue) =>
      if !err
        @set 'newVenue', new Plansandpictures.Venue
        Plansandpictures.Venue.get('loaded').add(venue)

  update: (params) ->

  destroy: (params) ->
    @get('venue').destroy (err) =>
      if err
        throw err unless err instanceof Batman.ErrorsSet
      else
        Plansandpictures.flashSuccess "Removed successfully!"
        @redirect '/venues'
```

**/app/assets/javascripts/views/venues/show.html**

```
<h4 data-bind="venue.name"></h4>
<h6>Description</h6>
<p data-bind="venue.description"></p>
<h6>Address</h6>
<p data-bind="venue.address"></p>
<h6>City</h6>
<p data-bind="venue.city"></p>
<h6>State</h6>
<p data-bind="venue.state"></p>
<a data-event-click="controllers.venues.destroy | withArguments venue">delete</a>
```

**/app/assets/javascripts/views/venues/index.html**

```
<h2>Venues</h2>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>State</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-foreach-venue="venues">
      <td data-bind="venue.name"></td>
      <td data-bind="venue.description"></td>
      <td data-bind="venue.address"></td>
      <td data-bind="venue.city"></td>
      <td data-bind="venue.state"></td>
      <td><a data-route="routes.venues[venue]">show</a></td>
      <td><a data-event-click="controllers.venues.destroy | withArguments venue">delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h3>Add a Venue</h3>
<form data-formfor-venue="controllers.venues.newVenue" data-event-submit="controllers.venues.create">
    <input class="new-item" placeholder="Name" data-bind="venue.name" />
    <input class="new-item" placeholder="Description" data-bind="venue.description" />
    <input class="new-item" placeholder="Address" data-bind="venue.address" />
    <input class="new-item" placeholder="City" data-bind="venue.city" />
    <input class="new-item" placeholder="State" data-bind="venue.state" />
    <input class="new-item" type="number" placeholder="1" data-bind="venue.user_id" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Venue" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller assumes it can fetch the venue via `@get('venue')`, but that's not necessarily set on the `index` view.  So change:

```
destroy: (params) ->
  @get('venue').destroy (err) =>
```

to:

```
destroy: (venue) ->
  venue.destroy (err) =>
```

And this ought to work from both contexts.